# C++ Win32 how to remove tab borders WC_TABCONTROL

Tags: c++, winapi, tabcontrol, ownerdrawn

Hi I am trying to convert an existing WC_TABCONTROL window with TCS_OWNERDRAWFIXED so that I have full control of its appearance.

But it seems all I can draw is the tab headers and even there I do not have much control on how the borders are drawn around tab page as well as tab headers.

Can someone point me to some material that explain how to custom draw, tab items and tab pages. I need to have control on how both the background and borders are drawn.

Comment: This is an article I wrote on drawing all of a tab control (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1786/Ownerdraw-Tab-Controls-Borders-and-All). It uses MFC but the principles should still hold.